# Detect batch output presence

Tags: batch

I've got a daily scheduled `.bat` batch script that runs [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org), and automatically commits that day's changes to my projects' source tree.  Now I've set it to run every day, including the weekends, since I also want it to pick up changes that I do when working on weekends.

Usually, though, I won't be working on weekends, and so it doesn't need to commit anything for that day (since there are effectively no changes).

Now fossil has the `changes` command, which can tell me beforehand what changes there are.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to set the errorlevel.  It just doesn't print anything to the output stream (or perhaps a single CRLF) if there is no change.

My question: is there a way to detect the presence of output from a batch file, so I can still use the `changes` command to detect whether to perform a commit or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `for /f` statement.  The syntax would be something like this:

`for /f %%i in ('fossil_command_goes_here') do`

Next, test `%i` for content and process if not empty

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) syntax for executing commands.  So if I just want to perform the commit once, I can do that, then `goto End`, I take it?

Comment: correct.  More accurately 'goto :EOF'  as :EOF is defined by default for all scripts.

Comment: I bow to you sir: I didn’t know about `:EOF` either — pity I can’t upvote twice... :-)

Comment: LOL.  It only means I've written too much in the old language.  Go Powershell!